# Convert an hexadecimal string to bytes in pure Solidity

Tags: oracles, signature, string, bytes, ecrecover

I am using Oraclize to recover a signature from a website. When I have it, I have to check if the address who signed it is correct. To do that, I would use [ECRecovery](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ECRecovery.sol) from Zeppelin.

The signature returned by Oraclize is a hexadecimal string like this

`0xaca7da997ad177f040240cdccf6905b71ab16b74434388c3a72f34fd25d6439346b2bac274ff29b48b3ea6e2d04c1336eaceafda3c53ab483fc3ff12fac3ebf200`

Though, `recover` expects the signature being a 65-bytes long `bytes`.

Is there any way to do the conversion in Solidity?

Thanks so much in advance.